# CKEditorにyoutubeの埋め込みプラグインを実装する方法

Tags: javascript

質問させて頂きます。

CkeditorをCDNで使用していて、そこにhttp://ckeditor.com/addon/youtubeのプラグインを実装したいのですが、 
うまく行きません。

config.jsに

CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'youtube', '/myplugins/youtube/', 'plugin.js' ); 
config.toolbar += [{ name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Youtube']}];

などとしたのですが、アイコンが表示されず、コンソールにもエラーなどが出ない為わからず困っておりました。

ご教授頂ければ幸いでございます。

Answer (score 1):

2点ほど確認してみて下さい。

`config.js`でプラグインの追加を指定していますか？

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'youtube';
};
```

自分の`config.js`が本当に読み込まれていますか？ `console.log`などは出力されていますか？